# Can I run a .EXE file in the server by using a Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, process, exe

I thought this would be a very easy task, so I think I´m retarded or something like that. I want to deploy a test application which follows this steps:

1. The user opens a Silverlight application using the browser
2. The user fills a Silverlight form and clicks on a "OK" button.
3. The button callback prepares the form to be passed as an argument to a .EXE program.
4. program.exe -argument is executed. If everything goes right, a result.txt is generated in a known path.
5. The Silverlight application reports result.txt

My only problem, by now, is the 4th step, because I can´t execute my .exe program without System.Diagnostics.Process. I've tried a COM solution, but it's not a good solution for this tests.

Comment: Why can't you use System.Diagnostics.Process? Isn't this running from a web service?

Comment: I don't know. I'm a newbie using Silverligth, but it seems to be some sort of limitation about .NET Framework. Just guessing, anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you should realize by now, Silverlight is actually running inside the browser locally using a subset of the .NET Framework with somewhat limited support for executing local code even with trusted status.

To be fair ... Silverlight may be over-kill for this, but if you wish to do it and you are running the process on the server:

- Create a new Silverlight project that supports RIA Services
- Create a DomainService and add a single Invoke method that looks like this:

  [Invoke]
  public string RunProcess( args ... )
- Create a button that calls the Invoke method on RunProcess and passes in the parameters.  As with all service calls in Silverlight this is an async callback and you will want to hook up a lambda to get the result when it is ready.
- In RunProcess, which is actually server-side, launch the process and simply return the output as a result of the method call as a string or some other type of data that makes sense to what you wish to display.

Comment: Good answer. There might be a caveat though. If Dani bISHOP is required to use an existing .exe that cannot be rewritten to code in the web service, there will still need to be some sort of notification system involved for when the results are ready. I guess the easiest way to do that would be to let the Silverlight client poll another web service method at regular intervals. That service method would check the file system for the appearance of the resulting file, parse it when it appears and return the result in a format that can be read and displayed by the client.

Comment: @Henrik This is certainly a consideration for long-running processes.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked Andrew's answer but your's is also interesting. I think I will keep the above solution (my current solution also) by now, sending an offline notification to the user when the processing had concluded. Apart from it, I think that your solution should implement another layer to restrict the execution of any process, but it's a good explanation indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered running a Windows Service on the server which watches for a file to show up in a specified directory, and then runs the EXE to generate the text file? Your silverlight process could just poll the output directory until the txt file shows up.

Comment: This is not what Windows Services are for. They don't run other programs or launch secondary executables.

Comment: Yes, thats something a service can do. On the server of course. Just make sure it isn't a GUI program.

Comment: Thank you. Thats the way I have implemented it but I wanted to know if it is possible to do in a 'direct' way. My current solutions is a stack of XML files containing all relevant information for each user request, ordered by generation time. A server process is monitoring the XML folder so it can detect new requests.